# Há alguma regra que determine quando a raiz do verbo poder é po ou pu?

Tags: verbos

O verbo poder tem formas verbais em que a raiz é *po* e outras em que a raiz é *pu*. Por exemplo: "se eu puder sair mais cedo, tu podes fechar a porta". Há alguma regra que determine quando usar *po* e quando usar *pu*?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Estou a assumir que a tua questão é sobre como se escrevem as formas. As formas que se escrevem com "o" são, sem exceção, também lidas /u/ se o "o" não fizer parte da sílaba tónica.

De resto, as irregularidades de "poder" são:

- uma forma irregular no presente do indicativo: *eu **posso*** (lido com "o" aberto) e não **eu podo* (com "o" fechado)
- um pretérito perfeito bastante irregular: ***pude*** / *pudeste* / ***pôde***  / *pudemos* / *pudestes* / *puderam*.

  - O "e", sempre que não final, é lido aberto e não fechado (compara com "comer", por exemplo).
  - A raiz é lida /u/ (até aqui é regular), mas escreve-se com "u" e não com "o" para distinguir do presente (compara "podemos" com "pudemos", ambos lidos /u/, só diferem no som do "e")
  - A exceção ao ponto anterior é a 3a pessoa do singular: *ele **pôde*** e não **ele pudeu*.
  - A 1a pessoa do singular tem uma irregularidade extra: para além de trocar "o" por "u", a desinência é "-e", não "-i".

Em consequência, os tempos derivados destes dois também são irregulares. Derivados do **pretérito perfeito** (também sempre lidos com "e" aberto):

- O **mais-que-perfeito**: *pudera* / *puderas* / *pudera* / *pudéramos* / *pudéreis* / *puderam*.
- O **imperfeito do subjuntivo**: *pudesse* / *pudesses* / *pudesse* / *pudéssemos* / *pudésseis* / *pudessem*.
- O **futuro do subjuntivo**: *puder* / *puderes* / *puder* / *pudermos* / *puderdes* / *puderem*

Já o **presente do subjuntivo** é formado a partir do radical da 1a pessoa do presente do indicativo. Isto é uma regra geral, não  exclusiva do verbo *poder*, que só não é observada por *haver*, *ser*, *estar*, *dar*, *ir*, *querer* e *saber* (e derivados). Temos portanto para este tempo: *possa* / *possas* / *possa* / *possamos* / *possais* / *possam*.

Answer (score 2):

Não conheço nenhuma regra, mas sei que a forma **"pu..." é usada no Pretérito Perfeito e no Mais-que-perfeito do indicativo, no Imperfeito e no Futuro do Subjuntivo.  Em todos os outros tempos verbais usa-se "po..."**

- eu pude, tu pudeste, ele pôde, nós...
- eu pudera, tu puderas, ele pudera, nós...
- se eu pudesse, se tu pudesses, se ele pudesse, se nós...
- quando/se eu puder, quando/se tu puderes, quando/se ele puder, quando/se nós...